# Jenkinsfile and env.GIT_BRANCH

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, branch, jenkins-groovy

I have a `Jenkinsfile` that uses a branching strategy.

I have an `if` statement in every `stage`.

My `release/*` conditional is not working. I want to have any `release/*` branches deployed to a staging env.

Is there any other way?

````
if (env.GIT_BRANCH == 'master' || env.GIT_BRANCH == 'release/*' || env.GIT_BRANCH == 'develop')```
````

Comment: I've used `env.BRANCH_NAME =~ 'release/'` before and that worked. Not sure what the name of it is though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a regular expression, since currently you are making a string comparison to literally `release/*`, which is unlikely to ever return true.

Utilizing a regular expression arrives at:

```
if (env.GIT_BRANCH == 'master' || env.GIT_BRANCH ==~ /release\// || env.GIT_BRANCH == 'develop')
```

which will match on any branch that begins with `release/`, which is what you are attempting to check for in the question.

You can find more information on Groovy regular expression operators in the [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_regular_expression_operators).

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? I've successfully used `env.GIT_BRANCH =~ 'release/'` in my pipelines.

Comment: @evolutionxbox What you wrote in your comment is a regex.

Comment: It is? I come from JS land, rather than groovy, so to me that was a string, not regex. What makes it regex?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I linked to documentation in the answer. You can find more information there if you are curious. Also, in general, regular expressions and strings are not mutually exclusive. One is a type and the other is an operator/method.

Comment: @MattSchuchard env.GIT_BRANCH =~ /release\//  this gave error
```WorkflowScript: 74: unexpected char: '\' @ line 74, column 74.
   || env.GIT_BRANCH =~ "/release\//"  || e
                                 ^```

Comment: I guess it didn't like the backslash

Comment: @Arsen Please use what I wrote in the answer, and do not modify it, and then it will work.